# mount.cifs without put user password again

Tags: automounting, cifs, kerberos

I'm already did the login with user an generate kerberos file:

```
#klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_625342619
Default principal: wecitrixteste@MYDOMAIN.CORPDOMAIN.COM

Valid starting     Expires            Service principal
15/12/16 14:22:17  16/12/16 00:22:17  krbtgt/MYDOMAIN.CORPDOMAIN.COM@MYDOMAIN.CORPDOMAIN.COM
    renew until 16/12/16 00:22:17
```

Then I tried mount the share:

```
mount.cifs -o domain=MYDOMAIN.CORPDOMAIN.COM,sec=krb5,user=USER,vers=2.1 //share.sharedomain.corpdomain.com/folder/folder /home/USER/sharefolder --verbose
```

but he always give me:

```
mount error(95): Operation not supported
```

If I put password manually, everything works fine:

```
mount.cifs //share.sharedomain.corpdomain.com/folder/folder /home/USER/sharefolder -o user=USER domain=DOMAIN sec=krb5 --verbose
```

or

```
mount -t cifs --verbose --source //share.sharedomain.corpdomain.com/folder/folder /home/USER/sharefolder -o user=USER,domain=DOMAIN,password="XPTOPWD666"
```

Any suggest?